CAPTCHA Issues in Headless Mode for TikTok URL Fetching
I'm trying to fetch URLs from a TikTok user page for a research purpose. It works fine with headless=false, but when I set it to headless=true, it triggers a captcha verification. Any ideas on how to fix this? I'm using playwright
import time
import random
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

def fetch_tiktok_video_urls(profile_url, max_videos):
    video_urls = []
    try:
        with sync_playwright() as p:
            browser = p.chromium.launch_persistent_context(
                user_data_dir="./user_data", headless=False
            )
            page = browser.new_page()
            page.goto(profile_url)
            page.wait_for_load_state('load')
            # page.screenshot(path="tiktok_profile_screenshot.png")
            simulate_human_browsing(page)
            # page.screenshot(path="tiktok_profile_scroll.png")
            while len(video_urls) < max_videos:
                page.mouse.wheel(0, random.randint(200, 500))
                simulate_human_browsing(page)
                # page.screenshot(path="tiktok_profile_video_scroll.png")
                video_elements = page.locator("a[href*='/video/']")
                links = video_elements.evaluate_all("elements => elements.map(e => e.href)")
                for link in links:
                    if link not in video_urls:
                        video_urls.append(link)
                if len(video_urls) >= max_videos:
                    break

            browser.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
    return video_urls[:max_videos]

def simulate_human_browsing(page):
    # Random scrolling
    scroll_steps = random.randint(3, 8)
    for _ in range(scroll_steps):
        page.mouse.wheel(0, random.randint(200, 500))
        time.sleep(random.uniform(1.5, 3.5))

    # Random mouse movements
    for _ in range(random.randint(2, 5)):
        page.mouse.move(
            random.randint(0, 800), random.randint(0, 600),
            steps=random.randint(5, 15)
        )
        time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 1.5))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tiktok_url = "https://www.tiktok.com/@nail_videos2024"
    urls = fetch_tiktok_video_urls(tiktok_url, max_videos=30)
    print("Fetched URLs:", urls)

I tried adding user agents like this:
browser = p.chromium.launch_persistent_context(
                user_data_dir="./user_data", headless=True,
                args=[
                    "--no-sandbox", 
                    '--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'
                ]
            )


setting brand: 'Google Chrome' works for me in headless mode for these scenarios.
